# Flutter MyContainer Color Issue

Tags: flutter

I'm encountering an issue with the Flutter app where the color property of MyContainer doesn't seem to work as expected in the MainScreen. Specifically, I have set the color parameter of MyContainer to different colors, but it doesn't affect the background color of the container.What am i doing wrong?Thanks in advance

```
Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: MyContainer(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: GenderWidget(
                        onPressed: () {
                          gender = "Women";
                        },
                        gender: "Women"),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: MyContainer(
                      color: Colors.green,

                        child: GenderWidget(
                  onPressed: () {
                    gender="Man";
                  },
                  gender: "Man",
                ))),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Widget class

```
class MyContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry margin;
  final  Color color;

  MyContainer({required this.child, this.margin = const EdgeInsets.all(12),required this.color}); // Default margin değeri verildi.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

      margin: margin, // Margin değeri instance variable olarak kullanılıyor.
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(15),
        ),
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}

class GenderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String gender;
  final Function onPressed;
  GenderWidget( {required this.gender, required this.onPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPressed(),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const Icon(Icons.person),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          Text(gender,style: textStyle,),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue might be with the hardcoded color in your `MyContainer` widget's `BoxDecoration`. You've set `Colors.white` as the color, which means it will always be white regardless of the color you provide when creating the `MyContainer`.

You should use the `color` parameter that you pass to `MyContainer` in the `BoxDecoration`. Here's the corrected `MyContainer` widget:

```dart
class MyContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry margin;
  final Color color;

  MyContainer({required this.child, this.margin = const EdgeInsets.all(12), required this.color});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: margin,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: color, // Use the color parameter here
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(15),
        ),
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

With this change, the `color` you pass to `MyContainer` will be used as the background color. Now, when you set the color in `MyContainer` in your `Row`, it should work as expected. For example:

```dart
MyContainer(
  color: Colors.white, // or any color you want
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  child: GenderWidget(
    onPressed: () {
      gender = "Women";
    },
    gender: "Women",
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to remove color from Container as you are using decoration property in Container?Meaning remove color from Container and set your desired color in decoration .And let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).